# Invalid value for key 'applicationintent'. (System.Data)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, availability-group

I have installed SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

The servers are clustered under WSFC and SQL Servers are in availability group with configured availability group listener. Availability group is working fine.

I've installed SSDT on all servers but no luck.

When I set `ApplicationIntent=Read-only` in additional connection parameters, I get this error :

> Invalid value for key 'applicationintent'. (System.Data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACcording to the [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.applicationintent?view=netframework-4.8), the possible values for `ApplicationIntent` are

- `ReadWrite`
- `ReadOnly`

None of those values have a **dash** in them! So use this :

```
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly
```

in your connection string